# Collapse Table without re-layout

Tags: jquery, css

### The Problem:

I am collapsing my tables with JQuery but am faced with one of two problems (depending on which route I take). If I collapse with `display: none` the whole table is reformatted. If I collapse with `visibility: collapse`, all of the space is still taken up from the table even though it's no longer visible.

---

### Photos to clarify

Expanded Table (bottom one for positioning reference)
[image: Expanded Table]
Collapsed Table with `display: none`
[image: Collapsed Table]
Collapsed Table with `visibility: collapse`
[image: Collapsed Table]

---

### Code

Javascript/JQuery:

```
function hideTable(name) {
    $('#' + name + ' tr:gt(0)').css("visibility", "collapse");
    //$('#' + name + ' tr:gt(0)').css("display", "none");
    $('#' + name).find("#collapse").attr("onclick", "showTable(\'" + name + "\')");
}

function showTable(name) {
    $('#' + name + ' tr:gt(0)').css("visibility", "visible");
    //$('#' + name + ' tr:gt(0)').css("display", "table-row");
    $('#' + name).find("#collapse").attr("onclick", "hideTable(\'" + name + "\')");
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="tables">
        <center>
                   <table style="width: 35%;" id="test">
           <tr id="collapse" onclick="hideTable('test');">
               <th>One</th>
               <th>Two</th>
               <th>Three</th>
               <th>Four</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>2147000000</td>
               <td>2147000000</td>
               <td>2147000000</td>
               <td>2147000000</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
       <br>
       <table style="width: 35%;" id="test2">
           <tr id="collapse" onclick="hideTable('test2');">
               <th>One</th>
               <th>Two</th>
               <th>Three</th>
               <th>Four</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>2147000000</td>
               <td>2147000000</td>
               <td>2147000000</td>
               <td>2147000000</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
       <br>
    </center>
 </div>
```

CSS (only css related to table format):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

The rest of the css is all looks, no more positioning/formatting has been done other than padding and borders of the table and it's cells

---

### What I'm looking for

I am looking for some work around to get the format of `visibility: collapse` (table headers stay aligned) and the size of `display: none` (invisible rows do not take up space). I have done my research and have come up empty handed.

If this question is poorly constructed by any means, please let me know before down voting it so I can make the edits, or, feel free to edit it yourselves. Thanks.

---

I have answered my own question. For my solution, see my answer or my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmvy44hy/7/).

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ??

Comment: Sure can. Creating it now.

Comment: I have created a html file at my local and seems that it is working fine.. So definitely some other css is effecting your layout ... Anyways if you can reproduce the issue in your fiddle than I think I can help you out..

Comment: Added only the code I presented in the post, still getting the error. The JSFiddle link is in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around for you, through CSS try putting fix padding in your header larger than what you expect in your tds.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7kjen9gf/

```
th {   
    padding: 30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for you.

Just add the another style to your tables :

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

Then the issue will be gone.. Cheers..

Comment: Its not the best solution, but it's something, I guess. I still hope to find something that wouldn't constrain the size of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Assign width for table columns so that it will not affect any layout issues.

```
 <tr id="collapse" onclick="hideTable('test');">
            <th width="25%">One</th>
            <th width="25%">Two</th>
            <th width="25%">Three</th>
            <th width="25%">Four</th>
 </tr>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/qmvy44hy/3/)

Comment: See Yunus's answer. While yes, it would work, it is not very dynamic and would cause some nasty line wrapping if the values in the cell were bigger in length than the values in the header

Comment: According to your comment, if you want you can use `text-overflow:ellipsis` to fix it in.

Comment: Then that just overflows into the next column

Answer (score 0):

### Final Solution

I have improved my methods to hide and show the table so it is completely dynamic. It allows for table collapsing without changing the size or position of the headers and works without constraining them.

```
function hideTable(name) {
    var rows = $('#' + name + ' tr:gt(0)');
    var columns = document.getElementById(name).getElementsByTagName('td');
    var count = (columns.length / rows.size());
    var bigArray = new Array(rows.size());

    for (var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
        bigArray[i] = new Array(count);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
        var count2 = rows.get(i).cells.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < count2; j++) {
            var bounds = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[j].getBoundingClientRect();
            bigArray[i][j] = bounds.width;
        }
    }


    var insertRow = document.getElementById(name).insertRow(rows.size() + 1);

    for (var x = 0; x < bigArray[0].length; x++) {
        var biggest = -1;
        for (var y = 0; y < bigArray.length; y++) {
            if (bigArray[y][x] > biggest) {
                biggest = bigArray[y][x];
            }
        }
        insertRow.insertCell(x).innerHTML = '<span style="float: left; width: ' + biggest + 'px;">...</span>';
    }

    insertRow.style.visibility = "collapse";

    for (var i = 2; i < rows.size() + 2; i++) {
        $('#' + name + ' tr:nth-child(' + i + ')').fadeOut();
    }

    $('#' + name).find("#collapse").attr("onclick", "showTable(\'" + name + "\')");
}

function showTable(name) {
    var v = $('#' + name + ' tr:gt(0)');
    document.getElementById(name).deleteRow(v.size());
    v.fadeIn('slow');

    $('#' + name).find("#collapse").attr("onclick", "hideTable(\'" + name + "\')");
}
```

The HTML would have to look like this:

```
        <table style="width: 35%;" id="test">
            <tr id="collapse" onclick="hideTable('test');">
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
                <th>Four</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!--content size not relevant to functionality.-->
                <td><span>Very large content</span></td>
                <td><span>Smaller content</span></td>
                <td><span>Smaller</span></td>
                <td><span>THE BIGGEST CONTENT IN THE TABLE</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Basic CSS would look like this:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Basically, the hide method scans through every row in the table and finds the largest width of the content inside the columns because that is what the table is formatted with. It then adds a filler row width floated fixed size spans in it equal to the size of the largest columns in each row. After than, it hides all other rows with `display: none` forcing the table to not take up any space. This filler row can be hidden also, but only with `visibility: collapse | hidden` or this will not work.

Comment: I think you have only made your solution complicated. While you could have used my solution initially and then wrote some java script for with issue. Any ways I am glad that its working for you.. Cheers :)

Comment: I don't think I could have, seeing as `table-layout: fixed` constrains the columns to 1/number_of_columns and does not allow re-sizing. My goal was to be able to fix my problem but still keep the same table layout.